# Paypal error "DEVELOPER ERROR: FILE SYSTEM CHECK FAILED" in iphone device

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, paypal

I have developed an application with paypal implementation. When i run this application on iphone simulator it works well. But when i run same application on iphone device, it display

> "Network error. Pay with PayPal not available. Please try again later."

error at the start of application. Also in my console(Log) it will display

> "DEVELOPER ERROR: FILE SYSTEM CHECK FAILED"

error. So please give me solution for that problem. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this kind of problem before. And in my case, its due to the iPhone itself. 
I don't remember where i read it but turns out, paypal does not work in most of jailbreak iphone, depending on how u jailbreak it. They claimed that its a security threat.

The only way to test whether its working or not is to restore the iPhone via iTunes and delete all the jailbreak traces or test it with another device which is not jailbroken, of course..

Comment: for now, u can read regarding the issue here.. http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/124558/paypal-button-does-not-activate-on-iphone ..

Answer (score 0):

PayPal also not very consistent with this error, I got different errors with different SDK versions

The only thing I found in PayPal forums:
Mobile Payment Library is not supported in jailbroken iPhone - see 
https://www.x.com/search/site/Mobile%20Payment%20Library%20is%20not%20supported%20in%20jailbroken%20iPhone

Answer (score 0):

If your phone is not jailbroken and is genuine, please look here for the answer that worked for me -> [Paypal error : FILE SYSTEM CHECK FAILED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9917292/paypal-error-file-system-check-failed/9924050)