# What API or code can I use to identify if the iPhone is jaibroken?

Tags: iphone, paypal, jailbreak

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I detect that an SDK app is running on a jailbroken phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413242/how-do-i-detect-that-an-sdk-app-is-running-on-a-jailbroken-phone)

I found out that PayPal's Mobile Payment Library is not supported in jailbroken iPhone - see https://www.x.com/search/site/Mobile%20Payment%20Library%20is%20not%20supported%20in%20jailbroken%20iPhone
and 
[Paypal error "DEVELOPER ERROR: FILE SYSTEM CHECK FAILED" in iphone device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606207/paypal-error-developer-error-file-system-check-failed-in-iphone-device)

What I wonder is what API they use to know that the phone is jailbroken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a duplicate of many similar questions.

Most jailbroken iPhones have Cydia and apt, so take a look at this:

http://petersteinberger.com/2010/03/detect-if-an-iphone-is-jailbroken/

Comment: ...and just like the other answers do point out, you should note that Cydia may not be installed, even though the OS is not jailbroken. A simple read check outside the sandbox will reveal if you are on a possibly compromised iOS.