# Paypal error : FILE SYSTEM CHECK FAILED

Tags: iphone, ios, paypal

I know there are two posts about this error on SO. Like every google result I found, the solution is : don't work with Jailbroken devices. But mine is clean and my client's one too.

I developed two apps with Paypal. The first works pretty good. The second shows the message DEVELOPER ERROR: FILE SYSTEM CHECK FAILED in debugger when Paypal button is initializing.

Of course, the same code (with same application ids) are declared in both apps.

An idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all people like me, who

- are using Paypal iPhone API since before august 2011
- have migrated their mac on osX Lion
- Now have this message during Paypal initialisation and after a new app compilation
- ... and does NOT have a Jailbroken device, of course

Here is the solution :

- Just download the new API version
- change [Paypal getInstance] by [Paypal getPayPalInst] in your code (WHY did they change that ?...)
- change

this callback method

```
- (void)paymentFailedWithCorrelationID:(NSString *)correlationID andErrorCode:(NSString *)errorCode andErrorMessage:(NSString *)errorMessage
```

by

```
- (void)paymentFailedWithCorrelationID:(NSString *)correlationID
```

And your done.

Comment: Worked perfect for me. Thanks a lot man. Found this nowhere and here it is :)