# Problems integrating paypal mpl in ios5 (paymentFailedWithCorrelationID:) (paymentLibraryExit)

Tags: ios, paypal

Ok I have been having really tough time with this and as I am new to ios dev, things are turning out really sick for me.

I am sure it must be a simple problem but I can't seem to figure this out.

After my initial try failed, I have repeatedly copied from paypal simplypayment demo and still does not work.

Here is the snapshot

[image: Error Note invalid parameter: target does not respond to (SEL)(payWithPayPal) target does not respond to (SEL) (paymentFailedWithCorrealationID:). target does not respond to (SEL)(paymentLibraryExit).]

It follows this with "Network timeout"

Answer (score 1):

i had face same issue a few days ago with paypal api try this one out

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9924050/803062